# Is there a topologizable group admitting only Raikov-complete group topologies?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

**Definition.** A group $G$ is called *complete* (resp. *non-topologizable*) if each Hausdorff group topology on $G$ is Raikov-complete (resp. discrete). It is clear that each non-topologizable group is complete.

**Question 1.** Does there exist a complete topologizable group?

In particular:

**Question 2.** Is the group $SO(3,\mathbb R)$ complete?

**Question 3.** Is the group $Sym(\mathbb N)$ complete?

A simple Baire category argument shows that each complete topologizable group is uncountable.

**Remark.** There are many examples of Polish groups admitting a unique $\omega$-narrow Hausdorff group topology (so, each $\omega$-narrow Hausdorff group topology on such a group is complete), see http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ssolecki/papers/AutomaticContinuity13.pdf.

In particular, $Sym(\mathbb N)$ is such a group.

Comment: There is a discontinuous homomorphism from $SO(3,\mathbb R)$ to ${\rm Sym}(\mathbb N)$. This will likely give a non-complete topology.

Comment: @Andreas Thom Thank you. This indeed gives a non-complete (even second countable) topology on $SO(3,\mathbb R)$! So, unlike to the group $Sym(\mathbb N)$ the group $SO(3)$ does not possess a unique $\omega$-bounded group topology? Only the unique totally bounded group topology! This is very interesting. Well, maybe the group $Sym(\mathbb N)$ will be an example of a complete topologizable group?

Comment: @Andreas Thom Could you give me a reference to the existence of a discontinuous homomorphism $SO(3)\to Sym(\mathbb N)$. Thanks.

Comment: It is Example 1.5 in [C. Rosendal. Automatic Continuity of Group Homomorphisms; Bulletin of Symbolic Logic 15,
no.2 (2009), 184-214.] with references to the work of Kallman and Thomas.

Comment: $SO(3)$ has also a unique SIN topology (not only totally bounded).

Comment: @Andreas Thom: SO(3) has at least two SIN-topologies: compact and discrete. Maybe you had in mind a unique $\omega$-narrow SIN-topology? Also thanks for the reference to the paper of Rosendal.

Comment: You are right. What I know is that it has a unique polish topology and every homomorphism to a polish SIN group is continuous.

Comment: @Andreas Thom If a group $G$ has a unique Polish topology, then each homomorphism $h:G\to H$ to an $\omega$-narrow topological group is continuous: to prove this fact one should first reduce the problem to metrizable (and hence separable and eventually Polish) group $H$, then take the diagonal product of $G$ into $G\times H$ and use the uniqueness of the Polish topology to conclude that the topology on $G$ inherited form product coincides with the original Polish topology, which yields the continuity of the homomorphism $h$.

Comment: This argument implies that the compact topology of $SO(3)$ is not a unique Polish topology on this group. Or I am missing something?

Comment: If $h$ is not continuous, then I do not see how one can use the separability of $G$ to get $H$ separable. Moreover, even if $H$ is separable, then $(1 \times h)(G)$ is not closed in $G \times H$. So the induced topology from the product is not polish (as it is not completely metrizable).

Comment: I think one can come up with a non-topolizable group along the following line: find a non-toplogizable ring $R$ and consider $\text{SL}_3(R)$. Note that group operation and suitable commutators operation retrive the ring structure on the subgroup having 1's on the diagonal and 0's elsewhere but the upper-right corner. I suppose the algebraic closure of a finite field is an example of an infinite non-topolozable ring. So I suggest $\text{SL}_3(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p)$. The above sketch is not a proof, though.

Comment: @Andeas Thom You are right, using discontinuous homomorphism into a second-countable group one can produce a stronger a second-countable (but not complete) group topology on $G$.

Comment: @UriBader Are you sure that the algebraic closure of a finite field is non-topologizable? It can happen that it is topologizable using the technique of $T$-sequences of Protasov and Zelenyuk: just take a sequence of algebraic numbers whose algebraicity degrees tend to infinity very quickly and take the strongest ring topology in which this sequence tends to zero.

Comment: @TarasBanakh no, I am not sure at all. After making the comment I thought about it a bit and it indeed seems to me that *all* infinite fields are topolizable. While writing the comment I had in mind that, by valuation theory, all fields of char 0 and all fields of poitive char which have at least one transendental element are topolizable.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to come up with non-complete topologies on $\text{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ is by embedding
$$ \text{SO}(3,\mathbb{R}) \to
\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})\to
\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{C})$$
and then using a discontinuous automorphism of 
$\mathbb{C}$ to produce a discontinuous automorphism of 
$\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{C})$.
Knowing all the (not so many) closed subgroups of $\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{C})$, it is easy to deduce that the image of $\text{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ under such an automorphism is not closed, hence the induced topology not complete.

Another nice way to finish the argument is by making an identification of $\mathbb{C}$ with another algebraically closed field of the same cardinality, carrying a different topological structure. For this one can use the "$p$-adic complex field", $\mathbb{C}_p$.
One gets the embedding
$$ \text{SO}(3,\mathbb{R}) \to
\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})\to
\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{C})
\to
\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{C}_p).$$
Finally, to cope with Andreas' remark, note that
$\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{C}_p)$ has a countable permutation action. Indeed, this Polish group has an open subgroup, namely
$\text{SL}(3,\mathcal{O})$, where $\mathcal{O}<\mathbb{C}_p$ is the ring of integers.

Comment: I think that this is also the original proof of the statement I made (due to Kallman).

Comment: @UriBader Inspired by your answer: is it true that each infinite compact metrizable group does admit a non-compact second-countable Hausdorff metrizable topology?

Comment: @TarasBanakh this is true for infinite compact Lie groups, and more generally for compact groups with non-trivial identity component (as the latters are inverse limits of the formers). The remaining class is the class of profinite groups. I am not sure about this interesting case. Maybe one can (in some cases) use Nikolov-Segal theorem to show that the algebraic structure forces the topology.

Comment: @UriBader Thank you for the comment. I looked at the survey paper of Klopsch (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00343.pdf). It indeed can be helpful in resolving the profinite case. I wrote the problem on the existence of discontinuous homomorphism on compact topological groups here (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269124).