# Does $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ act faithfully on a countable set?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, lie-groups

Let $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ be the group of rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $S_\infty$ be the group of all permutations of $\mathbb{N}$. Is $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_\infty$?

This question is due to Ulam. It is discussed in V.2 of Ulam's "A collection of mathematical problems". It is also discussed in de le Harpe's "Topics in Geometric Group Theory", Appendix III.B. According to de la Harpe it was open as of 2003. Is it still open?

Ulam also asks the more general question of whether every Lie group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_\infty$. De la Harpe constructs homomorphic embeddings $\mathbb{R} \to S_\infty$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to S_\infty$. There is an obvious embedding $S_\infty \times S_\infty \to S_\infty$, it follows that any connected abelian Lie group is a subgroup of $S_\infty$. So it is natural to look at $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ or other low dimensional non-abelian Lie groups.

It is worth pointing out that we cannot hope to realize $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ as a subgroup of $S_\infty$ without using a lot of choice. Suppose that $G$ is a compact lie group and $f : G \to S_\infty$ is a homomorphism constructed without choice. Then $f$ is Baire measurable, so by the Pettis lemma $f$ is continuous, hence $f(G)$ is compact and connected. Finally, any compact connected subgroup of $S_\infty$ is trivial. (In general closed subgroups of $S_\infty$ are totally disconnected.) So a faithful action of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ would be rather different than the usual kinds of actions.

Comment: $SO(3)$ embeds into $SO_3(\mathbb C)$. Using choice, fix an isomorphism between $\mathbb C$ and $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$, giving an isomorphism between $SO_3(\mathbb C)$ and $SO_3(\overline{\mathbb Q_p})$. Then doesn't $SO_3(\overline{\mathbb Q_p})$ act faithfully on $SO_3(\overline{\mathbb Q_p})/SO_3(\overline{\mathbb Z_p})$, which is countable because it is the union over all finite extensions $K_p$ of $\mathbb Q_p$ with ring of integers $\mathcal O_{K_p}$ of 
the countable $SO_3(K_p)/ SO_3(\mathcal O_{K_p})$?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/269008/89334

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From MathSciNet:

Thomas, Simon Infinite products of finite simple groups. II.
J. Group Theory 2 (1999), no. 4, 401–434.

Summary: "(...) In the course of our classification proof, we also show that if $K$ is a field of cardinality $2^\omega$ and $G$ is a non-trivial linear group over $K$, then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $1<[G:H] \le \omega$."

[This is almost the same since enlarging $G$, we can always assume $G$ is simple, say $G=\mathrm{PSL}_m(K)$, and then the induced homomorphism $G\to \mathrm{Sym}(G/H)$ is injective. The proof uses countable valuations as well.]

---

Ershov, Yu. L. ; Churkin, V. A. On a problem of Ulam. (Russian)
Dokl. Akad. Nauk 399 (2004), no. 3, 307-309.

Theorem 1. Every linear group over a field with continuum cardinality (in particular over the field $\mathbf{R}$ of all real numbers or over the field $\mathbf{C}$ of all complex numbers) can be embedded (as an abstract group) in the permutation group of a countable set.

(Unlike S. Thomas, they were aware of Ulam's question. On the other hand they were visibly not aware of S. Thomas paper.)

Answer (score 30):

This is possible (filling in some details in the argument from [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403275/does-mathrmso3-act-faithfully-on-a-countable-set#comment1032615_403275)).

We use choice to fix an isomorphism $\mathbb C \cong \overline{\mathbb Q_p}$. Using this, we embed $\mathrm{SO}(3) \subset \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb C) \cong \mathrm{SO}_3(\overline{\mathbb Q_p})$.

We let $\mathrm{SO}_3 (\overline{\mathbb Q_p})$ act on the set $\mathrm{SO}_3 (\overline{\mathbb Q_p})/\mathrm{SO}_3( \overline{\mathbb Z_p})$, where $\overline{\mathbb Z_p}$ consists of the elements of $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ that are integral over $\mathbb Z_p$.

This action is faithful since an element acts trivially if and only if all its conjugates lie in $\mathrm{SO}_3( \overline{\mathbb Z_p})$, and conjugating by an element of a split maximal torus, we can see that this forces the element to lie in that torus, hence to lie in every split torus, thus lie in the center, which is trivial.

(If, instead of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, we had a group like $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ with center, we could mod out by the integral elements congruent to $1$ mod $p$)

The set $\mathrm{SO}_3 (\overline{\mathbb Q_p})/\mathrm{SO}_3( \overline{\mathbb Z_p})$ is countable. Indeed, every class in it is represented by some element in $\mathrm{SO}_3 (\overline{\mathbb Q_p})$, which must lie in $\mathrm{SO}_3(K_p)$ for some finite extension $K_p$ of $\mathbb Q_p$, and thus arises from a class in $\mathrm{SO}_3( K_p)/ \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathcal O_{K_p})$ where $\mathcal O_{K_p}$ is the ring of integers.

The set $\mathrm{SO}_3( K_p)/ \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathcal O_{K_p})$ is countable by a standard argument - it is a countable union of the compact sets of matrices with bounded negative valuations, and because $\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathcal O_{K_p})$ is open, the topology is discrete.

Because there are countably many extensions $K_p$, the set is countable in total.

Comment: Very nice. In the fourth paragraph, did you mean that an element acts trivially if and only if all its conjugates lie in $\mathrm{SO}_3( \overline{\mathbb Z_p})$?

Comment: @GHfromMO yes, exactly.

Comment: this feels like it should work for $\mathrm{Gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ as well. that and the structure theory of lie groups might get one up to connected lie groups.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg: Hence for every connected Lie group?

Comment: @MarkSapir One group that the argument doesn't obviously work for is the universal cover of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$. I'm not sure if it can be modified to handle that case.

Comment: If it works for $GL_n$ then it should work for its subgroups?

Comment: @MarkSapir Yeah, if I remember correctly every connected lie group can be built up by taking semidirect products of subgroups of $\mathrm{Gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, so it might be enough to show that a semidirect product of groups which act freely on countable sets acts freely on a countable set, which seems plausible.

Comment: This very argument was, to my knowledge, first used by Simon Thomas about 20 years ago (he told me later he wasn't aware of Ulam's question). The argument actually extends to the case when $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbf{R})$ is replaced with an arbitrary subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ whenever $K$ is a field of cardinal $\le 2^{\aleph_0}$. [Oops, I see this latter fact was already pointed out in the comments. Anyway it's known.]

Comment: I've already thought about this question for non-linear Lie groups, say for the two-fold cover of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbf{R})$ (or the universal cover). It sounds to me delicate and should involve some K-theory.

Comment: @Ycor  I accepted your answer as the answer. I am still curious to know about general Lie groups. I would guess that if the universal cover of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ works out then any connected Lie group works.

Comment: by Hilbert's fifth problem any locally compact connected topological group is pro-Lie. Now, there certainly will be locally compact groups that are not subgroups of $S_\infty$, for example for cardinality reasons. I wonder if any separable locally compact topological group is a subgroup of $S_\infty$.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg instead of separable you should ask "second countable" or equivalently "metrizable separable". Indeed, there are separable compact groups of cardinality $2^c$, while $|S_\omega|=c$.

Comment: oh, of course, thanks.  So I guess what I really wonder is if every Polish group is a subgroup of $S_\infty$, or at least if every locally compact Polish group is.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg for Polish groups there are many known counterexamples, e.g., $\mathrm{Homeo}(S^1)$ (keyword: "small index property"). The question about locally compact Polish groups would be worth asking separately.

Comment: @YCor Oh yeah, and the small index property gives you automatic continuity for morphisms to $S_\infty$. (Apparently I have forgotten everything I used to know about Polish groups.) So that rules out a lot of interesting examples of Polish groups. This makes the question "which groups act freely on a countable set" more interesting, cool.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg you mean "faithfully", not "freely". The groups acting freely on a countable groups. The question which groups act faithfully on a countable set has been quite studied from the mid 1950s on (de Bruijn, Scott, McKenzie...).